# A formula for calculating which method would be most efficient, with factors of time, cost to produce, and units produced

Tags: dragon-city

Does anyone know a formula for calculating which option would be most efficient, with factors of time it takes to produce batch of units, total cost to produce the units, and units produced?? So here goes- bear with me here lol

Option. A.
Time. 180min.
Cost. $150,000.
Units. 2,250u.

Option. B. 
Time. 360min. 
Cost. $15,000. 
Units. 500u.

Option. C. 
Time. 120min. 
Cost. $5,000. 
Units. 200u.

Option. D. 
Time. 30min. 
Cost. $1,000. 
Units. 75u.

Option. E. 
Time. 5min. 
Cost. $250. 
Units. 25u.

Option. F. 
Time. 30sec. 
Cost. $50. 
Units. 5u.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its easier to see which one is best, if you convert everything to only one minute:

Option. A. Time. 180min. Cost. $150,000. Units. 2,250u.

> A) Cost. $833.33 Units. 14.16u

Option. B. Time. 360min. Cost. $15,000. Units. 500u.

> B) Cost. $41.66 Units. 1.3u

Option. C. Time. 120min. Cost. $5,000. Units. 200u.

> C)  Cost.41.66  Units. 1.6u

Option. D. Time. 30min. Cost. $1,000. Units. 75u.

> D) Cost. 33.33  Units. 2.5u

Option. E. Time. 5min. Cost. $250. Units. 25u.

> D) Cost. 50  Units. 5u

Option. F. Time. 30sec. Cost. $50. Units. 5u.

> D) Cost. 100  Units. 10u